# ASP.NET MVC choosing object from list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have two classes Item and Category. Items may belong to a single category. In the implementation I am using NHibernate and Item has a Category property (of type Category). Both classes are entities.

I wonder how to make it possible in a view for editing an item to be able to choose a category for example from a list or drop-down list. There are HTML helpers like Html.DropDownListFor but I don't know how to make it work when I need to select an object (NHibernate doesn't make CategoryId for Item accessible). Could anybody help me with the problem?

Thanks in advance
Lukasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using view models in all cases. So no matter how your NHibernate models look like you are trying to display a drop down list in the view. So as always you start by defining a view model that will hold the necessary information to be used by this view:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then you would have a controller action which will fetch the model from a repository and map it to this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Category category = ...
    // Example using AutoMapper
    CategoryViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryViewModel>(category);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and in the view simply:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItemId,
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text")
)
```

If you don't use view models you will be struggling to adapt your existing models to situations for which they weren't meant to be.

Comment: How to reasonably deal with the fact that no category may be selected for an item?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemberId, new SelectList(ViewBag.membersDD as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Name"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberId)
</div>
```

Where "Id" is name of property (from Member entity), which is used as a value for option. Second parameter is for option's text. In my case its a Name property of Member.

And I fill membersDD in controller this way:

```
ViewBag.membersDD = memberProvider.GetMembers();
```

I am using Entity Framework, don't know if its same with NHibernate.

Btw: This snippet is from my edit action for Task entity (which is assigned to some Member, which you can pick from dropdown list).

Comment: Unfortunately NHibernate doesn't make the foreign key accessible (like MemberId in your example with EF)

Comment: Uh...how do you get related entites then?

Comment: As I have written there is Category property of type Category. So to set it you need to do something like: `item.Category = category;`